# Wrong default dropdown list items selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, windows-server-2012

We have an Asp.net MVC application that has several dropdown lists on an input form.

We populate the lists as below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, SelectLists.Title)

public class SelectLists
    {
        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Title = new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Title", Value = "", Selected = true},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Mr", Value = "Mr"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Mrs", Value = "Mrs"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Miss", Value = "Miss"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Ms", Value = "Ms"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Dr", Value = "Dr"}
        };
    }
```

The default selected value is correct straight after a deploy onto our production environment but after time, what seems to happen, is that for all dropdowns, random values start to get selected on page load.

When we inspect the element on the form the `selected="selected"` attribute is set on the incorrectly displayed value on the offending dropdowns.

When we re-deploy the application the issues seems to temporarily go away, this is leading us to believe it could be an issue with IIS?

The application is running on IIS on a windows server 2012 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Is this passed to the view with a view model or ViewBag/Session?

Comment: What is the value `model.Title` when the View loads?

Comment: @JB06 Is what passed to the view?

Comment: @markpsmith it's set to default empty string

Comment: @ahammond The collection for the dropdown

Comment: @JB06 it's neither, the collections are returned from static methods on the `SelectLists` class

Comment: Are you using static methods to fill other dropdowns in your site? If so, do those ever have a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from the rather helpful folk at Microsoft on this. They suggested to remove the static lists and pass non static lists through the ViewModel. Having static information on a web application means this data is stored in the application domain in IIS and can be affected under load.